# Ajax POST to C# WCF WebService, 404 not found

Tags: http-status-code-404

I have a simple HTML page with javascript and an Ajax POST for calling a WCF WebService which I have made.

What the HTML page does, is to gather all the info from user input, wrap it in json and it should call the webservice.

The webservice should receive the Ajax POST, deserialize json into an object and insert it into the DB.

I have the WCF service published under my localhost IIS Server, but I get the error 404 not found. I also have the HTML page hosted in a different application, under the same website, in the same IIS localhost.

What could be the problem? I am trying to fix this for 2 days now, with no succes.

So this is my code:

Ajax post:

```
        $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "http://localhost/wcf_test/Service1/InsertUpdateIndividualEpxert",
                    data: JSON.stringify({individualExpert}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: onDataReceived,
                    error: onDataError
            });

function onDataReceived(data) 
{
    console.log('Everything is good!');
}
function onDataError() 
{
    console.log('Not working mister!');
}
```

WCF Interface:

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "InsertUpdateIndividualEpxert/{json}")]
    void InsertUpdateIndividualEpxert(string json);
```

WCF Web.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Service1_HttpBinding">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Service1_EndpointBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Service1_ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1_ServiceBehavior" name="WS_Experts.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
      behaviorConfiguration="Service1_EndpointBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="Service1_HttpBinding"
      contract="WS_Experts.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had just 2 problems.

1. In the service interface, **UriTemplate** should have been "**InsertUpdateIndividualEpxert**" and **NOT** "**InsertUpdateIndividualEpxert/{json}**"
2. I wrote "**Epxert**" instead of "**Expert**".

The tool I used to figure this out was **Google Chrome's "PostMan"**(not advertising anything, just giving full specs), which gave me the error I could understand "Endpoint not found" ... It was at that moment I knew where I messed up!

Right now I'm getting a "405 Method not allowed", but that my friends is a different ball game!

Happy coding everyone!